# Database localization in Django

Tags: django

I am using `.mo` files for localization in Django.
Also, in my database, I store some translated text in different fields, such as:

`name_en, name_es, name_de` (they are all columns in each row).

What will be the best method to choose the correct field inside a template?

i.e.:
`{{ name.some_method }}` will generate the correct translation based on the current localization.

Thanks,

Meit

Comment: Just wondering, why you're keeping translations in database? Why not store them to Software Localization Platform. What you could do is to use .po files and additionally JavaScript to localize those that are not in .po files. Then translation happens on client-side and you don't waste expensive server resources to look translations from your database. See e.g. http://www.getlocalization.com/library/api/get-localization-translate-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two method for doing this, one in your view and the other one is in the template...

1. In view:

Probably you keep the user language information somewhere so,

```
user_lang = 'es'
obj = Somemodel.objects.get(pk=123434)
obj.local_name = getattr(obj, 'name_%s'%user_lang)
```

So, you keep local translation in a specific variable of the instance and in your template you can use is as:

```
{{obj.local_name}}
```

But that might be costly if you wish to pass the template a queryset instead of a single instance. For a such usege you have to evaluate that value for each object in your queryset.

1. In template:

That is a more complex way of solving the porblem in the template...

Define a [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags) and pass object_id, and local language information and get the translated text using a similar **getattr** function. But in that point, if you wish to use this for more than one model, you probably have to pass a [content type information](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#module-django.contrib.contenttypes) for your template tag too, such as:

```
{% get_translation <object_id> <content_type_id> <local_language> %}
```

And in your template tag function, do something like:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

....
cont_obj = Content_type.objects.get_for_id(<cotent_type_id>) #get the related model 
obj = cont_obj.get_object_for_this_type(pk=<object_id>) # get your object 
return getattr(obj, 'name_%s'%<local_language>)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look at http://goodcode.io/articles/django-multilanguage/ Here’s a simple solution that may fit your use case and is easy to implement and understand.

Comment: Please add details to your answer from the link. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Django Transmeta](http://code.google.com/p/django-transmeta/), it work the same way as what you've done (DB fields with language code) but it's a more complete solution. It already deal with the template stuff, etc.

You can check [Model Internationalization](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ModelInterNationalization) and [Django Packages](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-translation/) for more info and ideas in this domain.